# Sequence of probability spaces: Is it a thing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I'm working  with a sequence of probability spaces.  Here are some details:

I roll a six sided die. My sample space is: $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.
Let $P$ be the uniform probability on $\Omega$. Then I have this probability space:
$(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega), P)$.

If I roll the die $n$ times, then my sample space is $\Omega^n$.
Let $P^n$ be the uniform probability measure on the $(\Omega^n,\mathcal{P}(\Omega^n)$.
Then I have this probability space:
$(\Omega^n,\mathcal{P}(\Omega^n), P^n)$.
I have a random variable $X$ on this probability space.
Expectation values over this probability space would conventionally be written as $E[X]$.

But now I want to generalize this to a die with $q$ faces, and eventually I'm going  to take the limit as the number of faces becomes large.  As far as I can think, the only way to handle this is to create a distinct probability space for each $q$.  So I guess I'll put a subscript on $\Omega$ to indicate the number of die faces: $\Omega_q=(1,2,3,...,q)$.   The sample space of $n$ rolls is $\Omega_q^n$.  I can extend the uniform probability measure to $n$ rolls of a $q$-sided die, and write this as $P^n_q$.
So I have a series of probability spaces I'll write as $(\mathcal{\Omega_q^n},\mathcal{P}(\Omega_q^n)P^n_q)$, $q = 6,7,8,...$.

Now the random variable I'm interested in can also be generalized to an $q$ sided die, and I'll write this as  $X_q$.

I'd like to express then expectation of $X_q$ over $(\mathcal{\Omega_q^n},\mathcal{P}(\Omega_q^n),P^n_q)$ for a general $q$.  I guess I'll write this as:

$E[X_q] = \int_{\Omega_a^n} X_q dP_q^n$

Does this make sense?  I tried to find out  how other people have dealt with a sequence of probability spaces, and I found nothing.  If I google "sequence of probability spaces", then I get nothing.  Is there a reason why I can't find precedence for this work?

Comment: You don't need a different probability space for every die roll. Try searching instead for "sequence of random variables". The standard example is an infinite sequence of coin tosses.

Comment: I  do understand the infinite sequence of coin tosses.  What I'm interested in is a sequence of die with increasing number of sides: A six sided die, a seven sided died, and eight sided die, ect.  Each one of these die would have its own probability space, I think.

Comment: Your probability space can be the interval $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure. To determine the value of the 6-sided die, divide $[0,1]$ into 6 equal-size intervals. To determine the value of the 7-sided die, divide each of those intervals into 7 equal-size subintervals, etc.

Comment: That might just work.  In other words, make the random variable do the work.

Comment: Could you write an answer?  I dont' study probability, I just want to be able  to write down the expectation over (0,1]^n in the limit of n to infinity.  I'm slightly familiar with the Kolmogorov's theorem, but I really don't want to get into it because it would be a huge distraction to my paper. I just need a way to write down this expectation value in one line and move on.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do, actually. It seems like really you have a function $X_q:[q]^n\to\Bbb R$ (where $[q]$ denotes $\{1,\dots,q\}$) and want to take $\lim_{q\to\infty}E(X_q)$, where $E(X_q)=\frac1{q^n}\sum_{v\in[q]^n}X_q(v)$ since the dice are fair. Is that right?

Comment: If that's the case, you don't need any measure-theoretic machinery - you're just taking the limit of a function that happens to be defined with reference to a (finite, discrete) probability distribution.